# HMAC-SHA implementation on JavaCard

Tags: hmac, javacard

I am trying to implement RFC-2104 HMAC on JavaCard smart cards. I seem to be getting the wrong results. Am I missing or misinterpreting something from the RFC-2104 ?

Code:

```
public class HMACSHA {

private MessageDigest md = null;
private static final byte IPAD = (byte) 0x36;
private static final byte OPAD = (byte) 0x5c;
private byte[] secretIpad;
private byte[] secretOpad;
private byte[] secretKey;
private short outSize = 20;
private short blockSize = 64;
private short ctr = 0;

/**
 * Init HMAC algo from RFC-2104. Setup the blocksize of the algo. Default SHA-1.
 *
 * @param hashAlgo
 * @param hmacKey
 */
public void init(byte hashAlgo, byte[] hmacKey) {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgo, false);

    if (hashAlgo == 4) {
        outSize = (short) 32; // SHA-256
    } else if (hashAlgo == 5) {
        outSize = (short) 48; // SHA-384            
        blockSize = (short) 128;
    } else if (hashAlgo == 6) {
        outSize = (short) 64; // SHA-512            
        blockSize = (short) 128;
    }

    secretIpad = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) blockSize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
    secretOpad = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) blockSize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
    secretKey = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) blockSize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);

    // Block size == key size. Adjust key.
    if ((short) hmacKey.length > blockSize) {
        md.reset();
        md.doFinal(hmacKey, (short) 0, (short) hmacKey.length, secretKey, (short) 0);
    } else {
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(hmacKey, (short) 0, (short) hmacKey.length, secretKey, (short) 0);
    }

    // Setup IPAD & OPAD secrets
    for (ctr = (short) 0; ctr < blockSize; ctr++) {
        secretIpad[ctr] = (byte) (secretKey[ctr] ^ IPAD);
        secretOpad[ctr] = (byte) (secretKey[ctr] ^ OPAD);
    }
    ctr = (short) 0;
}

public void doFinal(byte[] msg, short offset, short length, byte[] workBuff, short workOffset, byte[] outMsg, short outOffset) {
    if (md != null) {
        // hash(i_key_pad ∥ message)
        md.reset();
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(secretIpad, (short) 0, (short) secretIpad.length, workBuff, workOffset);
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(msg, offset, length, workBuff, (short) (workOffset + secretIpad.length));
        md.doFinal(workBuff, workOffset, (short) (secretIpad.length + length), outMsg, outOffset);

        //hash(o_key_pad ∥ i_pad-hashed)
        md.reset();
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(secretOpad, (short) 0, (short) secretOpad.length, workBuff, workOffset);
        ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack(outMsg, outOffset, (short) outSize, workBuff, (short) (workOffset + secretOpad.length));
        md.doFinal(workBuff, workOffset, (short) (secretOpad.length + outSize), outMsg, outOffset);
    }
}
```

}

The usage is to setup a sufficient size buffer or somewhere in the main applet class and then calling like the example below:

```
byte[] hmacBuff = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 128, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
hmac.init(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_256, hmacKey);
hmac.doFinal(incomingMsg, (short) 0, (short) incomingMsg.length, hmacBuff, (short) 0, outgoingMsg, (short) 0);
```

I double checked it with a standard Java implementation with the following parameters:

```
HMAC Key Bytes(16):8A560AB02C32377FE3D1BEABE666A19B
HMAC Challenge Bytes(16):8B4F35ADB59D27ABFE95A3CAAB0B613B
HMAC Result Bytes(32):646B96BA38B73847D080E25F843C1E1DE3E8D973DBE6AFC6D402604554E7A7F6
```

And the card's result is `5CB05D1B2CD3F711A853F7166366246743C58509E84D6B8B6C37FF00D6F07619`. Assuming the HMAC keys are properly synchronized in the JavaCard and on the sample desktop application. Am I missing something in my HMAC source code ?

Comment: I tested your code on my card and it produces the correct output, not the wrong one you posted! I changed only those things I had mentioned in my previous comments (my card does not support `ArrayLogic`). Is your `hmac` a fresh instance? If not, there can be a problem with old `blockSize` from previous algorithm.

Comment: It's not a fresh instance. So I have to reset the blockSize everytime ?

Comment: Yes, try it, please. If you use it first with SHA-512 and then with SHA-256, the blockSize remains 128, although it should be 64 again.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. It might have been the blockSize and so on. Now it looks better.

Comment: Careful on memory allocation. The byte[] hmacBuff = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray() will allocate new RAM each time being called. Consider moving it into init() or at install..

Comment: @David, thanks for the reminder. Noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines caused the issue:

```
if (hashAlgo == 4) {
        outSize = (short) 32; // SHA-256
        //!!! missing: blockSize = (short) 64;
} else if (hashAlgo == 5) {
        outSize = (short) 48; // SHA-384            
        blockSize = (short) 128;
} else if (hashAlgo == 6) {
        outSize = (short) 64; // SHA-512            
        blockSize = (short) 128;
}
```

For SHA-256 the `blockSize` remains unchanged, so SHA-256 after SHA-384 or SHA-512 inherits the wrong value (128 instead of 64).

---

There are a few more things to improve:

- `outSize` is not necessary, use `md.getLength()` instead. `outSize` must not be stored in persistent memory, it is rewritten very often. This applies to `blockSize`, too.
- do not create new instances of `MessageDigest` each time you call `init`, you will run out of persistent memory. Create all instances you need in the constructor.
- `ctr` must not be stored in persistent memory. It is a temporary variable and should be moved to RAM. You rewrite this variable very often and it can damage your card.
- `ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepack` should be replaced with `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic` from standard Java Card library - your applet would be faster and more portable
- create all buffers you need just once, not each time you call `init` (`secretKey`,`secretIpad`,`secretOpad`). Btw, you could have just one buffer and keep offsets only...
- call `md.reset()` only when it is necessary, you do not have to call it each time before `md.doFinal(...)`

---

The last (obvious) note: If supported by your card, always use `Signature.ALG_HMAC_SHA_XXX` instead. It will be much faster than any solution you can implement in Java Card on your own.

Comment: ... and probably more secure. CMAC may be even more secure as block ciphers are usually better protected against side channel attacks.